# Is it possible (and a good idea) to create Airflow dags dynamically based on the results from a database?

Tags: airflow

I realize this question has been asked before but I wanted to word it very simply. I am running Airflow v1.10.10 using Astronomer. Each dag run (daily) may have a different number of tasks. This number of tasks will be defined by the number of rows in a database table for that given dag run (i.e., that day).

I will run a query in the dag file and create a list as such:

`list = client.query(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = {{ds}})`

Then I will create the tasks based on the size of the list:

```
for i in range(1, len(list)):
    sample_airflow_operator(name=i + '_operator') >> sample_airflow_operator(name=(i+1) + '_operator')
```

and so on. I realize this is a crude example that doesn't cover when i = 0 or i = len(list) but I'm not worried about that.

If we define this dag to be daily, would the dag be successfully created each day, with a different number of tasks each day (depending on the results of the query I mentioned above)? Can Airflow execute the `list` query before every dag run? Would this be possible while keeping the dag on and maintenance free?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not creating DAG, you are creating tasks inside the dag, the short answer is **this will work**.

This is not a common practice in my knowledge but with some known downsides, I think it makes sense to do so for very peculiar usecases.

However few things to keep in mind,

- Do not use `depend_on_past` or `wait_for_downstream`  as `True` for any task which is dynamically generated. Tasks with these settings check previous execution and if there is no previous execution, they will not run.
- DAG UI (Tree mode) will show tasks based on latest execution only.
- DAG UI (graph mode) will show tasks based on what was present in dag when dag was executed. However I am not sure if you will be able to re-run an old taks which is not present in current DAG. So this is a compromise.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, I'll apply depend_on_past to a previous task which will be static each time. The UI comments make sense as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good to hear. Could you please mark this answer as 'acceped'

Comment: I'm just waiting to see if there is any other input. Thanks again.